# Jquery not working in IE6 and 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Hello Stack Overflow!

Pretty bad problem. None of my Jquery is working in IE6 and 7. I have googled around for solutions and have fiddled but to no avail! I have tried all the different document ready, Jquery function wrappers with no success. My code is as follows

Jquery inclusion

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Script file inclusion

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/js/script.js"></script>
```

And finally my code

```
jQuery(function() {
    var timer = 0;     
    $('.item').hide().each(function() {
        $(this).delay(timer).fadeIn('slow');
        timer += 500;
    });
});
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Do you have a live link?

Comment: If you put an `alert('jQuery Rocks!')` just before the line `jQuery(function() {` it appears?

Comment: What you labeled as "Jquery inclusion" is actually jQuery UI.  Are you actually including jQuery anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include regular jQuery before including jQuery UI.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Also, `fadeIn` will not work in IE6, as IE6 does not support transparency.

Comment: I do have it included. Sorry forgot to add it to my post. I have it all working in ie8+ and all the gooduns chrome etc. Just ie6 and 7

Comment: I just tested in both IE6 and 7 and it works fine in both (except no fading in IE6). The error is probably elsewhere in your code.

Comment: So there is no jQuery fadeIn support in Ie6?

Comment: It won't "fade", it will just show the box in IE6. But I wouldn't worry too much about supporting IE6.

Comment: It will fade in IE6, try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/bhpNm/ Tested with a vitual machine that has true IE6 installed on Windows XP

Comment: Really? Strange... I have true IE6 on my virtual machine and it isn't fading.

Comment: It should fade just fine considering IE6 does support alpha transparency through the filter just like IE7 and 8. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. What does your HTML markup look like? If it is invalid, IE may have tried to "fix" it causing the structure to not be what you expect, or not ran scripts at all.